# Getting error while Create a new Merchant Account on google play

Tags: android-pay, google-play, merchant-account

I have to add a paid application to play-store. I have successfully created the developers account, after that I am getting this error (while creating the new Merchant Account on google play):

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about setting up an online merchant account.

Comment: @computerfreaker means i can't ask for help :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 1):

Here is the steps to creating Merchant Account on Google play..

http://www.jeweleffects.com/instructions/merchantaccount.html

[See also this](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/188924?hl=en&ref_topic=3163841)

Thanks